# Change \parskip around itemize environment

Tags: lists, itemize, parskip

I want to have a non-zero `\parskip` between the paragraphs, but avoid having it around the "inline" itemize.

I could temporarily change it around each environment, but I have a lot of them in my document.  I could also redefine the `itemize` environment and introduce a `\vspace*{-\parskip}`, but I'd prefer a cleaner way.  Changing `\parskip` inside the environment is useless as it only works inside the group.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\parskip=6pt
Praesent hendrerit velit at magna tempus, at malesuada augue lacinia. Pellentesque at malesuada est, vel varius enim. In egestas massa et finibus ultricies. Donec felis erat, placerat et sodales in, egestas non mi.

% >> parskip here!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
% >> no parskip here
\begin{itemize}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{itemize}
% >> no parskip here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

% >> parskip here!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

Packages like `paralist` and `enumitem` did not seem to solve the problem in presence of `\parskip`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

latex uses `\topsep` as the local version of `\parskip` in that context so just set `\parsep` to whatever you need, however if setting without using enumitem or similar package you need to set it indirectly as article sets up each first level list using a predefined set of parameters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength\parskip{6pt}

\makeatletter
\def\@listI{\leftmargin\leftmargini
            \parsep 4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@
%            \topsep 8\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
            \topsep\z@
            \itemsep4\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus\p@}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Praesent hendrerit velit at magna tempus, at malesuada augue lacinia. Pellentesque at malesuada est, vel varius enim. In egestas massa et finibus ultricies. Donec felis erat, placerat et sodales in, egestas non mi.

% >> parskip here!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
% >> no parskip here
\begin{itemize}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{itemize}
% >> no parskip here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

% >> parskip here!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

or perhaps you want

```
            \topsep-6pt
```

depending how tight you want the spacing.

Answer (score 5):

You also can easily do  that with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem} %
\newlength\docparskip
\parskip=6pt
\setlength{\docparskip}{\parskip}
\setlist{nosep, itemsep=0pt, parsep=0pt, before={\parskip=0pt}, after=\vspace{-\docparskip}}%
\begin{document}
Praesent hendrerit velit at magna tempus, at malesuada augue lacinia. Pellentesque at malesuada est, vel varius enim. In egestas massa et finibus ultricies. Donec felis erat, placerat et sodales in, egestas non mi.

% >> parskip here!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
% >> no parskip here
\begin{itemize}
  \item first
  \item second
\end{itemize}
% >> no parskip here
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

% >> parskip here!
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, this does not give me `0pt` space around the list.  Lists seem to use `\parskip + \topsep + [\partopsep]` to produce vertical spacing around the environment.   However, setting \topsep to negative value should fix it.

Comment: I didn't understand you didn't want the ‘normal’ parskip either.

Comment: @ftynse: I've modified my code. Is it like what you want now?

Comment: It does produce the output I wanted, but still uses `\vspace`. David's suggestion with negative `\topsep` should work with `\setlist{topsep=-6pt}` I suppose.

Comment: I had to use `\vspace` because you can't prevent what follows a list environment  to be considered a new paragraph, so that `\parskip` is applied. Writing `\topsep=-\parskip` amounts to the same.